# Forge Offline Latest Version *7 Js and Css file Where i need to found For Mobile devices Android,IOS

Tags: android, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am Looking for Javascript(Viewer3D.js) and style.css  **version *7** file For Mobile devices
please share the link or suggest any alternate solution to get those thinks
Advance Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the viewer on mobile is not different than running the viewer in a navigator. All you need is a webview. Note as well that the viewer has a EULA which I am copying here for your convenience which does not allow to use it as a copy (see last paragraph).
The URL to access the viewer are https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.css

For sure, if there is good reasons to make a copy of the viewer locally, please contact autodesk at forge.help @ autodesk.com and explain what are these reasons.

```
/*!
 * LMV v7.30.1
 * 
 * Copyright 2020 Autodesk, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * This computer source code and related instructions and comments are the
 * unpublished confidential and proprietary information of Autodesk, Inc.
 * and are protected under Federal copyright and state trade secret law.
 * They may not be disclosed to, copied or used by any third party without
 * the prior written consent of Autodesk, Inc.
 * 
 * Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:
 * 
 * The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by
 * Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be
 * delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.
 */
```